# Result occurs often with fast random select query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, random

I have this query to display 4 random photos on a website (I have it from here (when I asked for something faster than `ORDER BY RAND()`)):

```
(SELECT   `p1`.`id`, `p1`.`url`, `p1`.`hits`, `p1`.`created_at`,
    `users`.`username`,
    `users`.`displayname`
FROM     pics p1
JOIN
        (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                (SELECT max(id)
                FROM   pics)) AS id
        ) AS p2
JOIN     users
ON       users.id = p1.user_id
WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT   `p1`.`id`, `p1`.`url`, `p1`.`hits`, `p1`.`created_at`,
        `users`.`username`,
        `users`.`displayname`
FROM     pics p1
JOIN
        (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                (SELECT max(id)
                FROM   pics)) AS id
        ) AS p2
JOIN     users
ON       users.id = p1.user_id
WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT   `p1`.`id`, `p1`.`url`, `p1`.`hits`, `p1`.`created_at`,
        `users`.`username`,
        `users`.`displayname`
FROM     pics p1
JOIN
        (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                (SELECT max(id)
                FROM   pics)) AS id
        ) AS p2
JOIN     users
ON       users.id = p1.user_id
WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT   `p1`.`id`, `p1`.`url`, `p1`.`hits`, `p1`.`created_at`,
        `users`.`username`,
        `users`.`displayname`
FROM     pics p1
JOIN
        (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                (SELECT max(id)
                FROM   pics)) AS id
        ) AS p2
JOIN     users
ON       users.id = p1.user_id
WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
```

It is fast, but it seems, that one particular photo is displayed too often, about every 10th refresh of the page, or so. It has not id 1 (it has 1131), but is the 1st photo of a certain user.

Could it be, that somehow gaps in the `pics` table could be the reason? I have no idea what else could be the reason.

### edit:

`SELECT id FROM pics WHERE id < 1131 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;` outputs this:

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 923 |
+-----+
```

Comment: Yes, gaps can skew results of this method. Can you show the output of `SELECT id FROM pics WHERE id < 1131 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;` ?

Comment: I have edited. it looks like a large gap.

Comment: How are records inserted into `pics`? Are your gaps the result in records(pictures) removed?

Comment: values are copied from another table after reviewing uploads. yes, the gaps are the result of deleted pics.

Comment: I don't know what to do with this. Right now I am fetching all ids from `pics`, cache them for 1 hour and make `php shuffle` and `array_slice` to get 4 random photos. It are about 7000 rows in `pics`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) has 8 'fast' ways to pick a random row from a table.

[AI with gaps](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random#case_auto_increment_with_gaps) may be the best choice.

Or the [50/10](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random#case_50_10_trick) trick.

[Add a FLOAT column](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random#case_auto_increment_with_gaps) may work well for you.

etc.